# Does drinking dry water have same effect as drinking regular water?

Tags: human-biology, food

[Dry water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_water) consists of water droplets that have been coated with silica nanoparticles, which prevents the droplets from forming a liquid.

If a human swallows dry water, does it have the same effect as regular water? Or do the particles go through the digestive system without releasing water inside? Is it dangerous to "drink" dry water?

Comment: I suggest this question to be asked at the chemistry stack exchange.

Answer (score -3):

Human health effects associated with silica exposure, especially crystalline silica (0.5–10 µm), have widely been studied. Occupational exposure to crystalline silica induces silicosis in workers (a fibrotic lung disease) and is also associated with lung cancer, emphysema, and pulmonary tuberculosis (Leung et al.

so im gonna say if you just straight inhaled silica nano-particles  it would be very harmful but would say that the nano-particles passing through you should not be a big factor (i would not drink it just because it could hypothetically go into your lungs

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. We're looking for answers that provide explanation, context, and include references to reliable sources. Don't give your opinion; explain why your answer is right with appropriate citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed especially when they don't address the question (inhalation ≠ drinking). Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then delete or [edit] your answer accordingly.